# GDB debugging a coredump with missing symbol tables for a specific call stack

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

I got this weird crash and I have no idea how to debug the core dump since the call stack is missing symbols info for some reason, except for the last function:

```
#0  BIH::intersectRay<VMAP::MapRayCallback> (this=0x7f47b8339608, r=..., intersectCallback=..., maxDist=@0x7f493af8383c: 0, stopAtFirst=true, los=<optimized out>) at ../BIH.h:223
#1  0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#2  0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#5  0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#7  0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#8  0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#11 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#13 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#14 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#16 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#17 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#19 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#20 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#21 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#22 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
....
#749 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#750 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#751 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#752 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#753 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#754 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#755 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#756 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#757 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#758 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#759 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#760 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#761 0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
#762 0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#763 0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
#764 0x03010102464c457f in ?? ()
#765 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`


(gdb) info frame 0
Stack frame at 0x7f493af83830:
 rip = 0x930f0b in BIH::intersectRay<VMAP::MapRayCallback> (../BIH.h:223); saved rip = 0x307ff00000
 called by frame at 0x7f493af83838
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7f493af83438, args: this=0x7f47b8339608, r=..., intersectCallback=..., maxDist=@0x7f493af8383c: 0, stopAtFirst=true, los=<optimized out>
 Locals at 0x7f493af83438, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f493af83830
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7f493af837f8, rbp at 0x7f493af83800, r12 at 0x7f493af83808, r13 at 0x7f493af83810, r14 at 0x7f493af83818, r15 at 0x7f493af83820, rip at 0x7f493af83828

#1  0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info frame 1
Stack frame at 0x7f493af83838:
 rip = 0x307ff00000; saved rip = 0x7ff0000000000000
 called by frame at 0x7f493af83840, caller of frame at 0x7f493af83830
 Arglist at 0x7f493af83828, args:
 Locals at 0x7f493af83828, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f493af83838
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7f493af83830

#2  0x7ff0000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info frame 2
Stack frame at 0x7f493af83840:
 rip = 0x7ff0000000000000; saved rip = 0x30
 called by frame at 0x7f493af83848, caller of frame at 0x7f493af83838
 Arglist at 0x7f493af83830, args:
 Locals at 0x7f493af83830, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f493af83840
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7f493af83838

#3  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info frame 3
Stack frame at 0x7f493af83848:
 rip = 0x30; saved rip = 0x307ff00000
 called by frame at 0x7f493af83850, caller of frame at 0x7f493af83840
 Arglist at 0x7f493af83838, args:
 Locals at 0x7f493af83838, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f493af83848
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7f493af83840

#4  0x000000307ff00000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) info frame 4
Stack frame at 0x7f493af83850:
 rip = 0x307ff00000; saved rip = 0x7ff0000000000000
 called by frame at 0x7f493af83858, caller of frame at 0x7f493af83848
 Arglist at 0x7f493af83840, args:
 Locals at 0x7f493af83840, Previous frame's sp is 0x7f493af83850
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7f493af83848
```

The code is compiled with `-g -fvar-tracking -O2 -march=native`.

I had various dumps for various crashes that all had the symbol tables working and gave relevant call stacks and infos, but for some reason this specific crash is cryptic.

One thing I noticed is the same address numbers repeating over and over again, could it be some infinite loop or recursion of some sorts that is corrupting or overflowing the stack?
If that so, is there any way to get the top most functions in the call stack (e.g. any way to go above frame #765 or get the functions called before the overflow was triggered)?

I cannot set `$sp` or `jump` to any address due to that I cannot debug and step through the live program, just analyse the core dump.
I cannot replicate this crash, it happens on production from time to time. Also valgrind is out of the question.

Are there any `g++` compiler options or `gdb` flags that could help me with this?
Any pointers on how to debug such an issue is appreciated (if possible at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have no idea how to debug the core dump since the call stack is missing symbols info for some reason

**Part 1:**

The most usual reason for this kind of meaningless call stack is a mismatch between the binary that produced the core dump, and binary you use to actually analyze the core.

If you used `--build-id` at link time, or if your GCC is configured to use that linker flag by default, then you can verify the the binary matches (or doesn't match) the `core` using this procedure:

```
readelf -n /path/to/binary
```

This should produce output similar to:

```
$ readelf -n /bin/sleep

Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000254 with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.24

Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000274 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: c266a51e4b85b16ca17bff8328f3abeafb577b29
```

The build-id string `c266a51e4b85b16ca17bff8328f3abeafb577b29` is the output you care about. Assuming your binary has it, install `elfutils` package, then use

```
eu-unstrip -n --core /path/to/core
```

to see which binaries were used at the time the core dump was produced.

The output should look like this:

```
$ eu-unstrip -n --core /tmp/core
0x400000+0x208000 c266a51e4b85b16ca17bff8328f3abeafb577b29@0x400284 - - [exe]
0x7ffca5721000+0x1000 9c7cbcf6c957d8fc8e55b45a3c7a1556b38a3097@0x7ffca5721340 . - linux-vdso.so.1
0x7f491ad5a000+0x2241c8 d0f537904076d73f29e4a37341f8a449e2ef6cd0@0x7f491ad5a1d8 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x7f491a995000+0x3c42c0 cf699a15caae64f50311fc4655b86dc39a479789@0x7f491a995280 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so libc.so.6
```

Above you can see that this `core` dump was in fact produced by `/bin/sleep`.

If the executable build-id in `core` does not match your binary, you'll need to locate the binary with build-id matching your `core` before you can extract correct crash stack trace in GDB.

**Part 2:**

If the binary *does* match the `core`, then it is very likely that the stack is simply corrupt (due to e.g. stack buffer overflow).

> valgrind is out of the question.

Valgrind is *exceptionally* weak at detecting stack corruption anyway.

The current state of the art in debugging these kinds of problems is [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), which is significantly faster and may be fast enough to run in production.

If sanitized binary is not fast enough for production use, you may be able to set it up such that it processes some subset of inputs in "shadow mode" (the binary runs, but its output is discarded). Any effort you put into such setup will likely uncover 10s of new bugs, and will save you significant future debugging effort.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, sadly the issue was a corrupt stack indeed and was caused by some bad checks propagating some UB (caused by some NaN values) down the call stack. Will definitely take a look a the Address Sanitizer tho, thank you for the suggestion.